# Difference between 'int' and 'Integer' types

Tags: java, variables

I was wondering what the difference between the variable type 'int' and the variable type 'Integer' and what the uses of using both is. Thanks!

Comment: Ask Google, he is a good guy.

Comment: Additional info to answers: one of cases where you have to use `Integer` instead of `int` is when you need to specify generic type for integers like list of integers declared as `List<Integer>` is correct while `List<int>` is incorrect because generic types `<..>` can't use primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `int` is `primitive data type` where is `Integer` is a `wrapper class` (an Object).

If you need an object then `Integer` comes into picture and other `int` you know it already.

All the `Collection` class accepts only object in that case you can't use simple int primitive data type.

> An `int` is a primitive. It is **not an Object**. An `int` is a high performance, streamlined beast for calculating numbers.
>
> An `Integer`, is an Object that contains a single int field. An Integer is much bulkier than an int. It is sort like a box to contain the int.

For more info look at [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [Primitive wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, it often boils down to whether you want to have `null` as a potential value for your variable.  **Spoiler:**  You probably don't.  Though if you're handling data going into/coming out of a database, `null` suddenly becomes a legitimate data condition and not just a null-pointer error waiting to happen.  (Though you have to code very defensively when `null` is in the mix.)

Some very useful objects, like `Collection`s, will only work on other objects and not primitives.  That's another place where you'd want to use the object rather than the primitive, though when actually working with the data, I generally recommend converting it to a primitive at your first opportunity.